# Changing the innerhtml of many elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an ajax call that I'm using to populate a table with the result of a query on a different page. It works, but I'm about to have to do another similar ajax call and this structure of having to do `$(#Whatever_Selector).html(result[0]['Whatever_Index'])` is driving me crazy, but I can't seem to figure out how to get around it.

Maybe something using `.each` and using `$(this)` but I have no clue.

My script:

```
    $('#selection_project').change(function(event) {
        $.post('info.php', { selected_project: $('#selection_project option:selected').val()},
            function(data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                var project = result['selected_project'];
                $('#CTN').html(\"CTN - \"+project); 
                $('#Global_Project_Number').html(result[0]['Global_Project_Number']);
                $('#Project_Type').html(result[0]['Project_Type']);
                $('#Lead_Location').html(result[0]['Lead_Location']);
                $('#Local_Project_Number_1').html(result[0]['Local_Project_Number_1']);
                $('#Local_Project_Number_2').html(result[0]['Local_Project_Number_2']);
                $('#Local_Project_Number_3').html(result[0]['Local_Project_Number_3']);
                $('#Local_Project_Number_4').html(result[0]['Local_Project_Number_4']);
                $('#Local_Project_Number_5').html(result[0]['Local_Project_Number_5']);
                $('#Development_Location_2').html(result[0]['Development_Location_2']);
                $('#Development_Location_3').html(result[0]['Development_Location_3']);
                $('#Development_Location_4').html(result[0]['Development_Location_4']);
                $('#Development_Location_5').html(result[0]['Development_Location_5']);
                $('#Customer').html(result[0]['Customer']);
                $('#Duration').html(result[0]['Duration']);
                $('#Customer_Group').html(result[0]['Customer_Group']);
                $('#Average_Number_of_Pieces').html(result[0]['Average_Number_of_Pieces']);
                $('#Project_Name').html(result[0]['Project_Name']);
                $('#State').html(result[0]['State']);
                $('#BU_CC').html(result[0]['BU_CC']);
                $('#Start_Of_Production').html(result[0]['Start_Of_Production']);
                $('#Outlet').html(result[0]['Outlet']);
                $('#End_Of_Development').html(result[0]['End_Of_Development']);
                $('#Start_Of_Development').html(result[0]['Start_Of_Development']);
                $('#Project_Connection').html(result[0]['Project_Connection']);
                $('#Project_Manager').html(result[0]['Project_Manager']);
                $('#Chance_Budget').html(result[0]['Chance_Budget']);
                $('#System_TPL').html(result[0]['System_TPL']);
                $('#Chance_Forecast').html(result[0]['Chance_Forecast']);
                $('#Product_Family').html(result[0]['Product_Family']); 
                $('#Technology').html(result[0]['Technology']);
                $('#LL_SW').html(result[0]['LL_SW']);
                $('#Processor_Type').html(result[0]['Processor_Type']);
                $('#HL_SW').html(result[0]['HL_SW']);
                $('#Chassis_Type').html(result[0]['Chassis_Type']);
                $('#Technology_Development').html(result[0]['Technology_Development']);
                $('#Technical_Description').html(result[0]['Technical_Description']);
                $('#username').html(result[0]['username']);
                $('#Milestone_1').html(result[0]['Milestone_1']);
                $('#Milestone_2').html(result[0]['Milestone_2']);
                $('#Milestone_3').html(result[0]['Milestone_3']);
                $('#Milestone_4').html(result[0]['Milestone_4']);
                $('#Milestone_5').html(result[0]['Milestone_5']);
                $('#Milestone_6').html(result[0]['Milestone_6']);
                $('#Due_Date_1').html(result[0]['Due_Date_1']);
                $('#Due_Date_2').html(result[0]['Due_Date_2']);
                $('#Due_Date_3').html(result[0]['Due_Date_3']);
                $('#Due_Date_4').html(result[0]['Due_Date_4']);
                $('#Due_Date_5').html(result[0]['Due_Date_5']);
                $('#Due_Date_6').html(result[0]['Due_Date_6']);

            } 
        );            
    });
```

I'm about to populate another table with hundreds of `<td>`s, I don't want to have to use the above format!

How do I make some kind of loop to use the index of the array in the Jquery selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for your use case (with the given information), you can use [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the properties of an object:

```
$.each(result[0], function(key, value) {
  $('#' + key).html(value);
});
```

assuming all values have a corresponding id element.

Answer (score 0):

Just go over your `result[0]` object with a simple loop.

```
$('#selection_project').change(function(event) {
    $.post(
        'info.php',
        {selected_project: $('#selection_project option:selected').val()},
        function(data) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            var project = result['selected_project'];
            result = result[0];
            $('#CTN').html('CTN - ' + project); 
            for (el in result) {
                if ($('#' + el).length) {
                    $('#' + el).html(result.el);
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: this works too, I may implement this for the next ajax call. Thanks!